# Can I have a value constructor named "/""?

Tags: haskell, syntax

I've declared a recursive data type with the following structure:

```
data Path = GET | POST | Slash Path String
```

I'd really like to rename that last value constructor to `/` so that I can infix it in cute expressions like `GET /"controller"/"action"`. However, if I try to do so:

```
import Prelude hiding ((/))
infixr 5 /
data Path = GET | POST | Path / String
```

...then I get this:

```
Path.hs:4:30: parse error on input `/'
```

Those same three lines compile just fine if I replace `/` with `:/` or any other special character sequence beginning with `:`.

So, is there any way I can name my value constructor `/`? I know that I can just name it `Slash` and then declare a separate function:

```
(/) :: Path -> String -> Path 
(/) = Slash
```

...but that won't let me pattern match, as in:

```
request :: Path -> String
request path = case path of GET /"hello" -> "Hello!"
                            GET /"goodbye" -> "Goodbye!"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: Type classes, type names, and data constructors must begin with either a capital letter or a colon (some of this requires using a language extension). Everything else must begin with a lowercase letter or any other allowed symbol.

Note that type *variables*, which are normally lowercase identifiers, follow the same rules and do not begin with a colon.

See also [the GHC user's guide](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/data-type-extensions.html#infix-tycons) for enabling type operators. Data constructors are always allowed, I think.

Personally, in your case I'd just use `(:/)`. It doesn't look that bad, and after a while you get used to ignoring the colons. Some people like a trailing colon as well, especially if the data is "symmetric" in some sense.

Comment: Seeing `:/` all over my code would make me wonder why it was so disappointed.

Comment: @zinglon: Hrhrhrhrhr. Fortunately, pretty much any non-alphanumeric Unicode glyph is allowed in operators, so the emoticon possibilities are nigh-limitless. Especially with the parens like that to use it prefix, just imagine all the shift-JIS crap you could do that way!

Comment: Besides, one of the the nice things about Haskell is that you never have to *wonder* why your code is disappointed in you, GHC will tell you all about it.

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't do this.  In pure Haskell 98, user-defined type names and constructors must be alphanumeric and begin with an uppercase letter; this is [in section 4.1.2 of the Haskell 98 Report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#sect4.1.2).  In GHC, just as user-defined constructors with alphanumeric names must begin with an uppercase letter, user-defined constructors which are operators must begin with a `:`.<sup>1</sup>  (The same is true for user-defined type names.)  This is documented in [section 7.4.2 of the GHC manual](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/data-type-extensions.html).  I'd probably use `:/`, myself, with or without `/` as a synonym.

---

**1:** The reason for the "user-defined" qualification is that there are a few built-in exceptions: `->`, `[]`, `()`, and the tuple types `(,)`, `(,,)`, etc. as type names; and `()` and the tuple type constructors `(,)`, `(,,)`, etc., as type constructors

Comment: I see the rule, but do you know why it wasn't allowed for operators as data constructors without the `:` prefix? Is there any kind of notational ambiguity?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: You can think of ":" as being an "upper-case symbol" in terms; the reason data constructors need to begin with an upper-case letter or a colon is, as I understand it, so that we can tell what things are constructors without needing to go through all the imported modules.  This is relevant for deciding if a pattern match is well formed or is against a constructor vs. a variable.

Answer (score 2):

I think all constructor operators need to start with a colon, (but I may be wrong).

So you could do:

```
data Path = GET | POST | Path :/ String
```