# Can you use special syntax for custom data types, as in lists?

Tags: haskell, ghc

List is allegedly defined as something like: `data List a = Null | Cons a (List a)`,
But it has special syntax as we all know. I can see how `:` is just an alias for the `Cons` type constructor, but 1) how/where is this syntax implemented and 2) can I define my own special syntax for another datatype, like the `[whamlet|Hello World!|]` that Yesod uses.

Thanks.

Comment: You can also define custom operators by the standard syntax of the language; e.g. `data Stream a = a :> Stream a`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I have a value constructor named "/""?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348605/can-i-have-a-value-constructor-named)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be looking for the [OverLoadedlists](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#overloaded-lists) ghc extension.  This allows you to use list syntax `[1,2,3]` to initialize and pattern match on vectors, sets, and other structures. A few examples of how to set up the list overloading are provided with the link.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 2] :: Set Int
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] :: Vector Int
```

It does not currently handle heterogeneous lists and does not over load the `:` operator.

You might want to read the [trac page on the extension](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/OverloadedLists).

If you are looking for a generic cons operator you should look at the `Control.Lens.Cons` module in the 
[lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) package.  In particular the [`<|` operator](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.2/docs/Control-Lens-Cons.html#v%3a-60--124-). Copied from hackage documentation:

```
>>> a <| []
[a]
>>> a <| Seq.fromList []
fromList [a]
```

Answer (score 5):

The list syntax is defined in the source code for the compiler.

The syntax Shakespeare uses is called "quasi-quoter" syntax, and it too is special syntax, defined in the compiler.  You can make your own quasi-quoters.

Answer (score 1):

**1. How do I make my own binary operators?**

You can do this by wrapping your operator name (made entirely of symbols) in parenthesis and giving it a definition. In the case you mentioned, if you have the data constructor:

```
data List a = Cons a (List a) | Nil
```

then you can define:

```
(:) :: a -> List a -> List a
(:) = Cons
```

As for where it's implemented, it's [in the standard prelude](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/standard-prelude.html):

```
data  [a]  =  [] | a : [a]  deriving (Eq, Ord)
-- Not legal Haskell; for illustration only
```

(that comment is there as well) -- I think the actual implementation of lists is hidden by the compiler (because the brackets are syntactic sugar), but it's included in the Prelude.

**2. How do I define custom syntax?**

The Hamlet syntax is an example of a QuasiQuoter, which is implemented using [Template Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Template_Haskell#QuasiQuoters), which is a set of faculties for meta-programming Haskell. Custom syntax like this is not, in general, very easy to define.

Comment: Not that operators starting with colon (':') must be defined as data constructors, not as functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your own infix data constructor, start with a legal operator name, then prepend colon (':') for example:

```
data ExprF r = Lit Integer | r :+: r | r :*: r
```